# PHP installation configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, installation

So I have already installed Apache2 and Mysql on Linux Mint (the same as Ubuntu), Now I am trying to install PHP on Apache but I get a very strange error message :

```
configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.
```

I did some search on the Internet and I found out that these files were not embedded before in PHP, but they are now. I even checked for it myself in the PHP source folders and I found that specific file. Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually PDO is included on PHP core.
You must install the PHP and MySQL bundled packages.
Use `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Answer (score 0):

you should check your php version, you must have php version 5 to load PDO.