# Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h. while installing pdo_ibm

Tags: ubuntu, pdo, php-7

while installing **pdo_ibm** in a ubuntu system,
its shows

```
configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h.
```

pdo_ibm version - 1.3.4
php - 7.0.15

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554722/php-installation-configure-error-cannot-find-php-pdo-driver-h]PHP installation configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h

Comment: Ubuntu version : Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have same symptom with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and PDO_IBM-1.3.4  , apache2, php 7.0.35.